# Create the subclasses

Tags: iphone, uiview, subclass

I m new in iphone, I want to create the subclasses of the NSView Class, how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `NSView` class. It is `UIView` class and you can create using the following code:

```
@interface YourClassName : UIView {

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

First, [learn the language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html). Next, [follow the directions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23).